# Sphinx server shutting off / stopping on its own

Tags: sphinx

Has anyone else had problems with a sphinx search just stopping or turning off on its own?  After a short period of time Sphinx will shut down and I'll have to go back and restart it.

Can something trigger Sphinx to turn off?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly look in searchd.log!

That is the most likly place to have useful information.